# Set up H2O steam on local machine

Tags: h2o

I'm trying to set up H2O steam on a Linux VM.

What I did so far:

- Set up VM with Ubuntu
- Download and deployed file as described on official page: 
  http://docs.h2o.ai/steam/latest-stable/Installation.html
- Start jetty with the following command:

  java -jar var/master/assets/jetty-runner.jar var/master/assets/ROOT.war
- Start Steam with the following command:

  `steam serve master --superuser-name=admin --superuser-password=admin012`

(official page seems outdated, it suggests run with option `--admin=admin`, which gives error. After some search, I think `--superuser` is the new parameter?)

This seems to work, service starts with no error.

When I try to open http://localhost:9000 in Chrome to get the UI and do stuff, I'm prompted for username and passwort. Trying admin / admin012 doesn't work, but gives no error, too. UI just don't open.

Here I'm stuck.

If anyone would have step-by-step instruction, on how to get current version of H2O steam work, would be great.

Best regards,
Jochen